# Why are some values not included in my csv-export?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a csv export form mongodb:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db booliscraper --collection sold --query='{"location.namedAreas":"_id,Hägersten",constructionYear: {$lt: 1980}, objectType: "Lägenhet"}' --type=csv --fields '_id,listPrice,livingArea,soldDays,' > sold.csv
```

For some values, the soldPrice is missing:

```
ObjectId(5beca65c78f21248ab483320),4495000,63,456,
ObjectId(5beca65e78f21248ab483330),2350000,53,455,
ObjectId(5beca66678f21248ab483464),3195000,52,448,
ObjectId(5beca66978f21248ab4834ab),2495000,47,447,
ObjectId(5beca66f78f21248ab48354d),,42,442,
ObjectId(5beca67078f21248ab483570),5795000,85,442,
ObjectId(5beca67578f21248ab4835cd),4200000,62,441,
```

I looked up the sold object in Robo 3T and it seems to have the value in question

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5beca66f78f21248ab48354d"),
    "location" : {
        "address" : {
            "streetAddress" : "Sparbanksvägen 68"
        },
        "position" : {
            "latitude" : 59.29407363,
            "longitude" : 17.98445821
        },
        "namedAreas" : [ 
            "Hägersten"
        ],
        "region" : {
            "municipalityName" : "Stockholm",
            "countyName" : "Stockholms län"
        },
        "distance" : {
            "ocean" : 5907
        }
    },
    "rent" : 3179,
    "floor" : 2,
    "livingArea" : 42,
    "source" : {
        "name" : "Mäklarhuset",
        "id" : 204,
        "type" : "Broker",
        "url" : "http://www.maklarhuset.se/"
    },
    "rooms" : 2,
    "published" : ISODate("2017-10-13T09:12:35.000Z"),
    "constructionYear" : 1945,
    "objectType" : "Lägenhet",
    "booliId" : 3016715,
    "soldDate" : ISODate("2017-11-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "soldPrice" : 2600000,
    "soldPriceSource" : "bid",
    "publishedDays" : 407,
    "soldDays" : 442,
    "daysUp" : 35,
    "street" : "Sparbanksvägen Hägersten",
    "streetYear" : "Sparbanksvägen Hägersten 1945",
    "yearDay" : 321,
    "yearWeek" : 46
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--fields '_id,listPrice,livingArea,soldDays,'` -- That document you pasted does *not* have `listPrice`